# Do android app crash logs or system crash/kernel logs contain user data?

Tags: crashes, logging, system-error, crash-reports, application-error

Do app crash logs/reports contain user data from the app, such as note contents from a note app? And if there is a full android system crash or kernel panic, is that log saved to the phone including a snapshot of memory at the time or is it sent anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of self-duplicate but not answered: [Is phone data sent or saved in the event of a crash?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247789/44325), [Is Google keep note content data included in a crash report or error log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247788/44325)

Comment: There is no standard definition of what should be included in logs and what should be done in case of a system crash. Also there's no standard that defines the “private data” (some users may consider device model as private info, while for others nothing less than a password is a private thing). So there is no universal answer to this question. It depends on the app developers and OEMs / ROM developers. Generally app developers and OEMs collect users' private data (for profiling / target advertisements etc.) even if there is no crash.